# what curl command can i use to change the value to true on a JSON

Tags: json, curl

```
{
    "properties": {
    "test": {
        "value": false,
        "name": "abc"
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying below curl command but the value is not changing to true

`curl -u admin:password http://<host>/check.json | jq 'map(.properties.test.value = "true")' | curl -X PUT http://<host>/check.json`

Comment: What response are you getting back from the server when running the final `curl -X PUT` ?

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3471  100  3471    0     0  35060      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 35060

Comment: So the first part of the CURL command seems to be working as i can see the value changed to true, but it's not updating on the file. so may be something is not right with the curl -X put command ? @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7003720/msbit

Comment: You can add `--verbose` to the last cURL command to see the response code etc that you are receiving. Also, as @andrei-kovrov has mentioned, you can't pipe the output to cURL exactly like that, but you could add `--data @-` to read the output from the second command into standard in for the last. My suspicion is that you are receiving a `405` and that your server doesn't support updating the URL with `PUT`, but we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the result of the second command to the third one via pipeline this way.

You need to pass the JSON via `-d` to the second request as the body.

```sh
UPDATED=$(curl -u admin:password http://<host>/check.json | jq 'map(.properties.test.value = "true")')
curl -X PUT -d "$UPDATED" http://<host>/check.json
```

Comment: Ah yes that will be a problem too. You could also replace the `-d $UPDATED` with passing to stdin with `-d @-`.